# Facebook App - Post news - I want to be able to post on peoples walls when new content is availiable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've built an facebook app, and it works pretty well.

But for some reason I cannot find or cannot understand how I will be able to alert users that new deals are waiting for them in my app.

I'm using canvas.

All I want to do is alert users when I have new content(updated my Database). I can already post to users wall, through sdk. But i want to send it to all users

Any ideas please.

Comment: Why not just send a notification? Mass-posting to people's Feeds is probably considered spam.